# Prove Heisenberg uncertainty principle

Tags: measure-theory, integration, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable complex function on $\mathbf{R}$ s.t. the functions $x \mapsto xf(x)$ and $f'$ are in $L_{\mathbf{C}}^2(\mathbf{R},\lambda)$.
>
> Show that
> $$
> x|f(x)|^2dx
> \le 4\left(\int_x^\infty t^2|f(t)|^2dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_x^\infty |f'(t)|^2dt\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
> $$

and use that to prove Heisenberg uncertainty inequality:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x)|^2
\le 2\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2|f(x)|^2dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f'(x)|^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}dx$$

Well I'm reading through complex measures on Hilbert spaces and I'm not able to solve this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Better suited to http://Physics.StackExchange.com perhaps?

Comment: Well it would be suitable there as well. Since this is just the mathematical perspective I think this fits also well in here and I want to solve this purely by measure and integration theory so I guess this is the right place.

Comment: I would not post it in PSE. Questions focussing on mathematical methods or even asking for rigourous mathematical proofs of laws of physics tend either to be migrated to MSE or to become the target of unpolite comments by people who do not even know that a null denominator at a point can well make a function discontinuous and unbounded... (ex. of both things [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1655828/a-commutation-between-curl-and-integral/1680380#1680380))

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Is $L^2_{C}(R, \lambda)$ all function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} | f(x) |^2 d \lambda < \infty$?

Comment: Here's one idea: By the plancherel theorem we have $$\int_{\mathbb R} | f'(x) |^2 d \lambda(x) = \int_{\mathbb R} \xi^2 | \hat{f}(\xi) |^2 d \lambda(\xi).$$