# A commutation between curl and integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, physics, vector-analysis, distribution-theory

I have been struggling to understand the only derivation of Ampère's law from the Biot-Savart law for a tridimensional distribution of current (which, needless to say, is not the case of a linear distribution of current discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227477/amp%C3%A8res-law-from-biot-savart-law-for-linear-currents-with-multivariate-calculus)) that I have been able to find, i.e. Wikipedia's [*outline of proof*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law#The_Biot.E2.80.93Savart_law.2C_Amp.C3.A8re.27s_circuital_law.2C_and_Gauss.27s_law_for_magnetism), for more than a month with no result.

I was not excluding that Wikipedia's *outline of proof* is one of those cases, whose set I have been [told](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191572/trajectories-piecewise-smooth/191599#191599) to be non-empy, where physics, at least at some level, renounces the rigour of mathematics, until I was told that the proof is indeed [rigourous](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35467/discussion-on-question-by-self-teachingdavide-rigorous-proof-of-amperes-law-fro). Although I have recently [asked for an alternative proof](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234360/proof-of-amp%C3%A8res-law-from-the-biot-savart-law-for-tridimensional-current-distri) of the same entailment, the fact that it is not to be excluded that Wikipedia's *outline of proof* is rigourous has made me decide, as it has been suggested to me in [these comments](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35467/discussion-on-question-by-self-teachingdavide-rigorous-proof-of-amperes-law-fro), to ask for an explanation of the single steps that I do not understand of that *outline of proof*.

My first doubt starts at the first commutation between the integral and curl signs. I know that $$\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})\times\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|^3}=\nabla_r\times\left(\frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|}\right)$$provided that we read the components of $\nabla_r$ as ordinary derivatives (see below) in the sense of elementary multivariable calculus. The *outline of proof* says that $$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}):=\iiint_V\,d^3l\,\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})\times\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|^3}=\nabla_r\times\iiint_V\,d^3l\,\frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|}.$$What mathematical result justifies that commutation between integral and curl? I heartily thank you for any answer.

<sub>In order to take the problem on, it is obviously needed to understand **what the integral and the derivatives** in $\nabla$ **are**, but I am not sure about what they are. Since theorems such as Stokes' are usually applied when integrating $\nabla\times\mathbf{B}$, I would tempted to believe that the components of $\nabla_r$ are **ordinary derivatives of elementary multivariable**/vector **calculus**, but Dirac's $\delta$, which is a tool of the theory of distributions, "pops out" at a certain point in the *outline of proof*, and in the theory of distributions there exist **derivatives of distributions** which are a very different thing, although they are taken, as far as I know, with respect to the variables written as "variables of integration" in the distribution integral notation, while, here, we start with $\nabla_r\times \mathbf{B}$ with $r$, while the integral is $\iiint_V d^3l$ with $l$. As to the integral sign, I would tend to interpretate it as the **Lebesgue integral** $$\int_V\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})\times\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|^3}\,d\mu_{\mathbf{l}}$$ or as the limit of a **Riemann integral** (where $B(\mathbf{r},\varepsilon)$ is the [ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_%28mathematics%29#Balls_in_general_metric_spaces) centred in $\mathbf{r}$ with radius $\varepsilon$) $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\iiint_{V\setminus B(\mathbf{r},\varepsilon)}\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})\times\frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|^3}\,dl_1dl_2dl_3$$but, then, if the commutations between integral and differential operators used Wikipedia's outline of proof were licit for this interpretation, we would then conclude that $\iiint_V\,d^3l\, \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})\nabla_l^2\left(\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|}\right)$ $=\int_V \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})\nabla_l^2\left(\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|}\right)\,d\mu_{\mathbf{l}}$ $=\int_{V\setminus{\{\mathbf{r}}\}} \mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})\nabla_l^2\left(\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|}\right)\,d\mu_{\mathbf{l}}=\mathbf{0}$ even where $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r})\ne\mathbf{0}$, which must not be the case.</sub>

Comment: A question so specifically asking about a mathematical detail should be on Math.SE. Besides that, exchanging derivatives with integrals really comes down to exchanging the order of two limits. This is an incredibly well studied/described topic.

Comment: surf from a google search on Leibniz Rule or Leibniz Integral Rule. Indeed , it's well documented.

Comment: @igael Thank you so much! The problem is that I do know Leibniz rule as: if $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact and $f:V\times[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, $(\boldsymbol{x},t)\mapsto f(\boldsymbol{x},t)$ is such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}∈C(V\times [a,b])$, then
$\forall t\in[a,b]$$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_Vf(x,t)d^nx=\int_V\frac{\partial f(\boldsymbol{x},t)}{\partial t}d^nx$$but our integrand does not satisfy the assumptions...

Comment: If you're worried about the compactness of the domain just make a sequence of ever-larger domains, construct the limit, and commute that limit around just like the others. Or, better yet, think of improper integrals as a limit with a [partition of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity).

Comment: An a broader note, it would a lot easier to understand exactly what issue is confusing you if you could ask a question focused on that issue. I doubt the Biot-Savart law has anything to do with what you're really trying to understand, which, I think, is about commuting limits around. With that in mind, most of the post here is actually a distraction and is probably why it's taking you days (weeks?) to get answers to your multiple posts on this topic.

Comment: did you account of the approximations of magnetostatics ? not sure that it is a question for math.se

Comment: @igael Thank you again! What do you mean by the approximations of magnetostatic? Forgive me, but, I'm just trying to study some theory of electromagnetism by myself for the first time...

Comment: Nothing in the original post says anything about discontinuity or boundedness. How is a would-be answer writer supposed to know what you have in mind if it's not written down? :)  -1 because the question "What mathematical result justifies that commutation between integral and curl?" is too broadly worded to answer (at least, in light of this discussion revealing that you are interested in mathematical details). I'd be interested to see a revised post that focuses on the real issue at hand.

Comment: If you see that Ampere's law and the Biot-Savart law are equivalent for bounded, smooth functions, then anything else follows via limits. Even the $\delta$ function can be viewed as a short-hand way to write a certain limit. Also, what is this notation $\int_{V \setminus B}$?

Comment: Ampere law is not accurate with wires of complex shapes, short wires, misshapen solenoids or toroids. It is not surprising to get inconsistencies when equaling the 2 calculus. Chapters 9.10.1 & 9.10.2 of [direct pdf course](http://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/physics/exam-prep/magnetic-fields/biot-savarts-law-amperes-law/8_02_spring_2007_ch9sourc_b_field.pdf) may help to retreive the equality in the special cases. [source](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-02-physics-ii-electricity-and-magnetism-spring-2007/)

Comment: *Nothing in the original post says anything about discontinuity or boundedness. How is a would-be answer writer supposed to know what you have in mind if it's not written down?* If the would-be answer writer has ever studied calculus, (s)he knows that the denominator $|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|$ causes $(\mathbf{l},r_i)\mapsto |\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{l}|^{-3}\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{l})×(\mathbf{r}−\mathbf{l}​)$, with $\mathbf{r}=\sum_{i=1}^3= r_i\hat{\mathbf{e}}_i$, not to be continuous at the points where $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{l}$, nor bounded. [...]

Comment: [...] If he hasn't studied calculus yet, (s)he isn't supposed to try to answer a question about an outline of proof involving not only calculus, but even the use of Dirac's $\delta$.

Comment: *"What mathematical result justifies that commutation between integral and curl?" is too broadly worded to answer* Commutation between integral (Lebesgue, Riemann, notation for linear functionals...) and derivative signs isn't always valid, as I hope anybody here to know, and must be allowed by some mathematical result (is my English the problem?), as igael has understood, suggesting a theorem that I know in a form of it relating to volume integrals, but which I don't know in a form that can be applied to our integrand. Edited the OP for those not knowing the notation $B(\mathbf{r},\epsilon)$

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have found a proof. In fact, if the components of $\mathbf{J}:V\subset \mathbb{R}^3 \to\mathbb{R}^3$, are bounded and $\mu$-measurable, with $\mu$ as the $3$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, and $V$ is bounded and measurable according to the same measure, the following lemma

> Let $\varphi:V\subset\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded and $\mu_{\mathbf{y}}$-measurable, with $\mu_{\mathbf{y}}$ as the usual $3$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, where $V$ is bounded and measurable (according to the same measure). Let us define, for all $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $$\Phi(\mathbf{x}):=\int_V \frac{\varphi(\mathbf{y})}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}d\mu_{\mathbf{y}}$$then $\Phi\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and, for $k=1,2,3$, $$\forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^3\quad\quad\frac{\partial \Phi(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_k}=\int_V\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \left[\frac{\varphi(\mathbf{y})}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|}\right]d\mu_{\mathbf{y}}=\int_V \varphi(\mathbf{y})\frac{y_k-x_k}{\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^3}d\mu_{\mathbf{y}}$$

which is proved [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/commutation-integral-derivative-in-deriving-amperes-law.857283/#post-5380956), with $\varphi=J_i$, $i=1,2,3$, would allow the desired commutation between integral and curl signs.

For a complete proof of how Ampère's law is entailed by the Biot-Savart, I hope I have reached one [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234360/proof-of-amp%C3%A8res-law-from-the-biot-savart-law-for-tridimensional-current-distri/241101#241101).